# How to create my code formatting style in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know that I can press OPTION+CMD+L to format code.

But I don't know how to create my code formatter style in Android Studio.

For example, what I write is :

```
Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0]).appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format).appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units).appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays)).build();
```

I want format it to this:

```
Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();
```

Comment: Settings > Code Style > Java

Answer (score 1):

Under the preferences for Android Studio, you can define your own code formatting in the section below:

[image]

I think under wrapping and braces, you can define the bit you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find "Chained method calls" option in wrapping and braces.